# Socket Code creating new writers?

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

I have a code example with a while loop that has true in it.  I assume this runs forever until the program or class is stopped.  However, I'm confused as there is a new PrintWriter made each time it runs the while loop.  I would think this would be an issue.  There is also a new thread created.  Am I reading this code incorrectly.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  new VerySimpleChatServer().go();
}

public void go() {
  clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
  try {
    ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);

    while(true) {
      Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

      Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
      t.start();
      System.out.println(“got a connection”);
    }
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
} // close go
```

It looks as if, it only runs when a new connection is made, but what part of the code proves that.  It just looks as if a new writer and new threads are created constantly.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer will be created only when a socket is available because   `serverSock.accept()` is blocking (return when a socket is available in its queue).

Note: This code is broken and can easily throw `OutOfMemoryError` because it doesn't limit the number of threads created, consider using a [managed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead.

Comment: ooh, the ServerSocket accept() kind of keeps the while loop from continuing.. That didn't even occur to me as even a possibility. Thanks. I'll look into working with managed thread pools also.

Comment: @mc805 It *blocks* until an inbound connection occurs,.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new thread created every loop because it's in the while loop.

You have `while(true)` so unless you break the loop, it's going to continue forever.

Now to break down what's actually happening in the loop

`Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();`

The server accepts a new connection from a client.

```
  `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());`
```

A new PrintWriter object is created, using the new clients output stream. Notice that this is done for every client, because clients won't have the same output stream.

```
  clientOutputStreams.add(writer);
```

Assuming this is just a list of all the PrintWriters you can use to write to clients.

```
  Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
```

A new Thread object is created, not sure what's in ClientHandler but it must have some run method.

```
  t.start();
```

The Thread is started. The server can continue to accept new connections.

I hope that answers your question.